# KO viewmodel's property is available but viewmodel itself is empty

Tags: post, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel bound on a html page for submitting a form.

When I submit the form, the viewmodel itself is coming up as empty but the observable items within the viewmodel are populated.

Hence I am unable to post the viewmodel to the server as it is coming up null.

Please help!

My html:

> ```
> <p>First name:<input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p>
> <p>Last name:<input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p>   
> <p><button data-bind='click: saveUserData'>Submit</button></p>
> ```

And my script:

> ```
> function PersonViewModel() {
>     var self = this;
>     this.firstName = ko.observable();
>     this.lastName = ko.observable();
>     this.saveUserData = function () {
>         alert(ko.toJSON(self)); // alerts '{}' i.e. nothing
>         alert(ko.toJSON(self.firstName())); // alerts value of the firsTname
>         //do the post here
>     };
> };
>
> ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel());
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I found the root for this issue and am posting the solution here so that it would be helpful to anyone if they stumble upon similar issue.

**Solution:** Perform the binding (**applyBindings** function call) after the document is ready. i.e.,

> $(document).ready(function () {
>           ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel());
>       });

Thanks!